# How do you track inputs that were sent from SendInput in C++

Tags: c#, c++, keyboard, sendinput

I have two separate programs running at one time.

One of the programs is a virtual keyboard that causes keyboard presses when you click that respective letter on the GUI.  It uses SendInput() to make the keyboard commands and is coded in C#.

The other program is a game that takes in the physical keyboard presses as input, and I can change this code to whatever it needs to be to read inputs from the virtual keyboard.  This is coded in C++.

Right now, when both programs are running, the virtual keyboard can type things in notepad, but the game program doesn't respond to these inputs.  However, the game program can respond to physical keyboard presses.

I'm wondering if I could see what keyboard commands were sent through SendInput so that the game program can read it.  For example, if I press the up arrow on the virtual keyboard, the code in the game can use some function to detect that an up arrow command was issued.